# Play Audio (mp3, ogg) from sd card with AudioTrack

Tags: android, audiotrack

I want to play audio file from SD card with AudioTrack. I've tried with this code:

```
int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        int bufferSize = 512;
        AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        int i = 0;
        byte[] s = new byte[bufferSize];

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fin);

        at.play();
        while ((i = dis.read(s, 0, bufferSize)) > -1)
        {
            at.write(s, 0, i);

        }
        at.stop();
        at.release();
        dis.close();
        fin.close();
```

But it doesn't play audio file properly. Instead of original audio it plays some kind noise sound.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the following link i have found that  AudioTrack only plays PCM audio,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

And Please have a look on this code. 
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/
this is provided the information about how to  Play an MP3 file on an AudioTrack.

Hope this helps u .

Answer (score 3):

The AudioTrack class only supports PCM audio data, that's why you're hearing noise.

Use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) or [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) if you want to play compressed audio files like .mp3 and .ogg.
Alternatively you could decode the compressed audio in your app and write the resulting PCM data to an AudioTrack, but that's a much bigger task.