# AudioTrack plays static sound

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I want to play music tracks with AudioTrack class in android, using stereo with PCM 16 bit channel. Here's my code for **MusicListFragment.java**

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MusicListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private AudioTrack mAudioTrack;

    public MusicListFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_music_list, container, false);

        ListView musicListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.music_list_view);
        musicListView.setAdapter(new MusicListAdapter(getActivity()));

        int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
                22000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22000
                , AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        musicListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Music music = (Music) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[512];

        mAudioTrack.play();

        try {
            File file = new File(music.getPath());
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            int k;
            while ((k = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                mAudioTrack.write(bytes, 0, k);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter works fine, since I tested it using the **MediaPlayer** class. (I can provide my Adapter and other classes too, if you want. But I doubt they are the issue.) 
 My list view shows the title, artist and the album of musics and also stores each music's path. 
I could play musics easily with **MediaPlayer**, but I'm having problem using the **AudioTrack**. The code makes device play static sounds, like the old TVs when they have no signal! :) 
As you can see in adapter's on click listener, I'm
1. getting the music that is selected.
2. reading the music file into an **InputStream** 
3. and finally writing the bytes to the audio track instance. (I've also put the line: mAudioTrack.play() after the try, catch statement, no luck) 
 What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing the binary contents of a compressed audio file to the AudioTrack, perhaps? This won't work unless your music files are stored in raw, uncompressed format. AudioTracks use [PCM format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation). Even the header on a .wav file would sound like static, until you reached the raw samples.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @greeble31 answer, I understand my issue now, I searched about how to decode .mp3 and .wav files to PCM format and I found some useful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200812/play-audio-mp3-ogg-from-sd-card-with-audiotrack) and [here](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/) , in case anyone needs it.